# Django django.test django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager

Tags: python, django

Please assert type: 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager'.

In other words, how to import the module in order to assert that the field 'user.groups' is of type 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager'?

```
from django.db.models.fields import related_descriptors

# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ManyRelatedManager'
self.assertIsInstance(user.groups, related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager)

print(type(dummy_user.groups)) # <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager'>
```

Here's the error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ManyRelatedManager

Thanks

Comment: Tried my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make such an assertion on `user.groups` and `related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager`.

The `ManyRelatedManager` class is not accessible using import like `from django.db.models.fields import related_descriptors` because if you look at the source code of django, the `ManyRelatedManager` lives inside of `create_forward_many_to_many_manager` function.

P.S. I do not see any reasons why you want to check the type of `user.groups`. It is always the same and tested by django tests already.